# A more elegant way to iterate over arrays

Tags: ruby, arrays, ruby-on-rails-3, loops

Using the following set up:

```
north = [comp1]
east = [comp2, comp3, comp4, comp5, comp6]
south = [comp7, comp8]
west = [comp9, comp10, comp11]
companies = [north, east, south, west]
recruiters = ["Bob", "Bill", "Jane", "Josh"]
```

I want to iterate over each element of `companies` and assign one of the names to each element. I want to assign recruiter `"Bob"` to all the elements of `north`, recruiter `"Bill"` to `east`, recruiter `"Jane"` to `south`, and recruiter `"Josh"` to `west`.

One way would be to do something like:

```
north.each do |c|
  company = Company.find_by(name: c)
  company.assigned_recruiter = recruiters[0]
end
```

and that process would be repeated for the remaining elements but changing the index of the recruiters array.

Is there a more elegant way to do this?

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. Please provide sample output that you are looking for. Asking for more elegant code would be best on MAYBE Code Review. Since your code technically works, there is no issue to be solved, besides refactoring.

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
companies.zip(recruiters).each do |companies, recruiter| 
  companies.each {|company, recruiter| assign_recruiter(company, recruiter) }
end
```

I would also rename `companies` to `regions`.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it inline with a method for assignment.

```
north.each { |c| assign_recruiter(c, recruiters[0]) }
east.each { |c| assign_recruiter(c, recruiters[1]) }
south.each { |c| assign_recruiter(c, recruiters[2]) }
west.each { |c| assign_recruiter(c, recruiters[3]) }
```

with this somewhere accessible

```
def assign_recruiter(company, recruiter)
    c = Company.find_by(name: company)
    c.assigned_recruiter = recruiter
end
```

If you don't need the recruiters array for anything, you could replace `recruiters[x]` with the string literal.

Alternatively, you could put the arrays in a hash:

```
companies = { 
    north: [comp1]
    east: [comp2, comp3, comp4, comp5, comp6]
    south: [comp7, comp8]
    west: [comp9, comp10, comp11]
}
recruiters = {
    north: "Bob",
    east: "Bill",
    south: "Jane",
    west: "Josh"
}
```

Then you could iterate over the hash...

```
companies.each { |k, v| v.each { |c| assign_recruiter(c, recruiters[k]) } }
```